# Adding a method to the C# Controls class

Tags: c#, class, methods

I am trying to add two methods to the Controls class in C#, these classes being 'UpColor' and 'DownColor' so that I can set a buttons BackColor depending on whether the state of the button is 'up' or 'down'

I have tried using extension methods, however because extension methods are static is means that every time I select a different button it will use the previous buttons up/down color, instead of it's own.

Is there a way of adding to the Controls class so that I can get/set a Color?

I have decided to go down the route of adding a static class and to have a dictionary for each method. It's not what I wanted, but I should do the job..

```
    static class ButtonColors
{
    public static Dictionary<Control, Color> UpColor
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public static Dictionary<Control, Color> DownColor
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to add? `classes` or `methods`? Also you seem to misunderstand extension methods.

Comment: _"I have tried using extension methods, however because extension methods are static is means that every time I select a different button it will use the previous buttons up/down color, instead of it's own"_ - that's not how it's supposed to work. Extension methods don't "operate on one object because they are static", there must be something else going on. Show your code.

Answer (score 3):

You should extend the class accordingly:

```
public ClassWithColors : Control {
  // extended implementation
  public string UpColor { get; set; }
  public string DownColor { get; set; }
  // assuming types, change as needed
}
```

However, it's not clear which control class you're talking about, so assuming WinForms here. In principle it's the same for ASP.NET user controls and whatnot.

Comment: And how do you let, say, `Button` inherit this class?

Comment: I have tried inheriting from the Control class, however I cannot then create a new button

i.e. ClassWithColors button = new Button();

Sorry, I forgot to mention this is WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make "method", that takes handle of button and change its colors.